# What happens if I take out the sword in the Dark Forest?

Tags: divine-divinity

There's a sword within a stone in an area inside the Dark Forest asking me (in a rather rude manner) to take it out. The quest log says that maybe I should think twice about taking it out. What happens if I take it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Obvious spoilers ahead)

It's a side quest with possible severe effects on other side quests. Essentially, you will release a ghost that will attack you, after proclaiming itself to be Death or a servant of Death, with the will to kill everyone. It will come back to life no matter how many times you kill it, unless you seal it yourself again. If you don't seal it and choose to run away instead, the consequences are quite severe: the entire Dark Forest elf village minus Bronthion will be wiped out by the ghost.

That means you won't be able to finish any business started there, including anything related to the elf love interest, as she will die too. There is no way to bring them back to life, so the consequences are permanent.